# In moment.js where to find methods that mutate date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, code-documentation

Moment.js mentions that the data is mutable [here](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/) and therefore if you say:

```
var a = moment('2016-01-01'); 
var b = a.add(1, 'week'); 
a.format();
"2016-01-08T00:00:00-06:00"
```

The data in `a` changed when naively changing `b` without the use of `.clone()`

In the process of debugging I am uncertain whether bugs are caused by the logic of my code or by the data getting changed.  As a result I have been spamming `.clone()` everywhere which decreases readability.

**Is there a list of methods that mutate the data in moment.js?**

Examples:

- It is safe to assume methods such as `.add`, `.subtract`
- how about other methods such as `.diff`?
- how about the equals operator on two moments?

Is there list of such methods?  The docs are really good at showing what the code *can* do but I am having trouble finding what the code *does* do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frozen-moment) and avoid spamming the clone method. In generally, data mutates in moment.js and it generally creates bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would presume that all methods listed in the [MomentJS doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/) under the category of Manipulate and all setters will mutate your date.

Meanwhile, other methods and getters will not mutate your date. That will be the first rule that I will be using. When in doubt, use jsFiddle to perform a quick test to certify that there are no mutations involved.